# Браузер не находит сервлет для отклика

Tags: java, servlet, web.xml

Есть сервлет, который формирует простенькую анкету. [image: Вид анкеты в браузере]

После заполнения данных [image: Submit info]

Получаю ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Маппинг (web.xml) и сам сервлет:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyAnketa</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myAnketaPackage.MyAnketa</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyAnketa</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyAnketa</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>MyAnketa.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

[MyAnketa.jsp](https://github.com/Mykla/MyAnketa/blob/master/web/MyAnketa.jsp)
[MyAnketa.java](https://github.com/Mykla/MyAnketa/blob/master/src/myAnketaPackage/MyAnketa.java)

Если я правильно понимаю, метод doGet отработал, но почему-то не стартует doPost.

Где ошибаюсь?

Comment: Во первых ваш подход не оправдан. Разместите код представления в MyAnketa.jsp, а в MyAnketa.java код сервлета. Почему методы doGet и doPost   объявлены с такими модификаторами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Страница не найдена, потому что Вы замаппили сервлет на URL `/MyAnketa`, а форму пытаетесь отправить на URL `/myanketa`. Нужно исправить на:

```
out.println("<form method=\"post\" action =\"" + req.getContextPath()
+ "/MyAnketa\" >");
```

Адреса отличаются регистрами и URL'у `/myanketa` ничего не соответствует в Вашем приложении, поэтому и 404.

Comment: Спасибо! все получилось